# Promise to execute code after knn classifier tensorflow is finished

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, promise, tensorflow.js

Im using knn classifier in tensorflow.js from this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/knn-classifier). Sometimes it is a little bit slow of adding the new examples when doing transfer learning so I want to create a promise that waits for the new example to be added before a the code continues to execute. I havnt used promises a lot so Im a bit lost. I tried this

```
  new Promise(this.knn.addExample(logits, this.training)).then(
    console.log("print this message to the console after the training is done);
  );
```

but it doesnt work however.
I also tried this according to the [documentation on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp) but didnt work either

```
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    // Add the example to the training
    this.knn.addExample(logits, this.training)

    myResolve(); // when successful
    myReject(); // when error
  });

  myPromise.then(
    function(value) {
      console.log("print this message to the console after the training is done")
      /* code if successful */
    },
    function(error) {
      /* code if some error */
    }
  );
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is ``this.knn.addExample`` an async function ?

Comment: hm. it runs within  `async animate() { }` function. Im not sure if this makes it to a async function?

Answer (score 0):

In an async function, `await` can be used

```
async animate() {

  await this.knn.addExample(logits, this.training) // wait until the promise is resolved

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
const mypromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    /* if this.knn.addExample returns true/false 
       you may use it below instead of resolve(true)
    */
    this.knn.addExample(logits, this.training); 
    resolve(true);
});
mypromise.then((res) => {
    if(res) {
        // code you want to execute
    } else {
       throw new Error('This error explains why this.knn.addExample returned false');
    }
});
```